# Virtual-host setup with Apache HTTP Server v2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

What is the most common virtual host setup that is in use?
I've seen some different setups here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html
In other words, which of the above would you recommend to use?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Instead, you should state what you are trying to accomplish.  I.e., I want to setup multiple domains, etc..

Comment: Why it doesn't make sense? :| Anyway, OK, I'll edit...

Answer (score 0):

That URL lays out the plusses and minusses of all the different setups - did you have additional questions or did you not understand parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

The most common virtual host setup is the one that comes pre-configured in the Apache http.conf file.